# Make 2 <select> statements work and dont crash the script

Tags: javascript, html

Im putting multiples select in my code that are hidden and got a principal select that makes visible the other selec depending in the value selected, but when you choose a value in the second select it changes the second visible select to another, how can I prevent that to happen

Its a catalog in a static html that interacts with a SQL Server via php, so I need the select to compare it with the ID´s and make inserts and updates

This is the script:

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue){
                $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                $("." + optionValue).show();
            } else{
                $(".box").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
function myFuction(){
  //Getting Value
        //var selValue = document.getElementById("singleSelectDD").value;
        var selObj = document.getElementById("MENU");
        var selValue = selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value;
        //Setting Value
        document.getElementById("valorsel").value = selValue;
      }

</script>
```

And this are the  examples:

```
 <select name="MENU" id="MENU" onchange="myFuction()">
        <option value="" selected></option>
        <option value="1">Area</option>
        <option value="2">Bancos</option>
        <option value="3">CFDI</option>
        <option value="4">Departamentos</option>
        <option value="5">Empresa</option>
        <option value="6">Giro Comercial</option>
        <option value="7">Negocio</option>
    </select><br><br>
<p>Texto Global</p>
<input type="text" name="GLOBAL" id="GLOBAL" value="" placeholder="Texto global">
</div>
<div class="1 box">
  <p>Seleccione el Area deseada</p>
  <input type="text" name="Txt_Area" id="Txt_Area" value="" placeholder="AREA">
  <select name="AREA" id="AREA" placeholder="Seleccione Area deseada>
    <option value="" selected></option>
    <option value="1">AREA 1</option>
    <option value="2">AREA 2</option>
    <option value="3">AREA 3</option>
</select>
```

I want to be able of having both select on screen to insert or update the information

Comment: The php is on the action of my form, and I need to be able to read the select values to make comparation with the ID´s on my SQL tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having `$("select").change(function(){`, it's better that you have `$("#MENU").change(function() {` because otherwise it will detect all the select menus that are changing instead of just the first one like you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#MENU").change(function() {
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
      var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
      if (optionValue) {
        $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
        $("." + optionValue).show();
      } else {
        $(".box").hide();
      }
    });
  }).change();
});

function myFuction() {
  var selObj = document.getElementById("MENU");
  var selValue = selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value;
  //Setting Value
  //document.getElementById("valorsel").value = selValue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="MENU" id="MENU" onchange="myFuction()">
  <option value="" selected></option>
  <option value="1">Area</option>
  <option value="2">Bancos</option>
  <option value="3">CFDI</option>
  <option value="4">Departamentos</option>
  <option value="5">Empresa</option>
  <option value="6">Giro Comercial</option>
  <option value="7">Negocio</option>
</select><br><br>
<p>Texto Global</p>
<input type="text" name="GLOBAL" id="GLOBAL" value="" placeholder="Texto global">
</div>
<div class="1 box">
  <p>Seleccione el Area deseada</p>
  <input type="text" name="Txt_Area" id="Txt_Area" value="" placeholder="AREA">
  <select name="AREA" id="AREA" placeholder="Seleccione Area deseada">
    <option value=" " selected></option>
    <option value="1 ">AREA 1</option>
    <option value="2 ">AREA 2</option>
    <option value="3 ">AREA 3</option>
  </select>
```